# Follow Up Simple 2-Way Interactions

Tags: anova, spss, manova

After conducting a 3-Way in-between subjects ANOVA, I see there is a significant interaction among the 3 independent var, X*Y*Z (2 levels). As a follow up, I conducted a simple 2-Way interaction between X*Y to check if they were influenced by Z (Gender: Male and Female). Again, here, there was a statistically significant simple two-way interaction between X and Y for both Male, F(3,193)=2.803, p=0.041 and for Female, F(3,193)=2.704, p=0.047’. How do we write or deduce this result in plain language for a technical person to understand the connotation?

I noticed that in the 3-Way ANOVA output, X*Z was non-significant (p>0.05) on the dependent var; but in the follow-up simple-two way interaction, they are significant for Z (the 3rd independent var). Does that sound statistically correct?
Thanks

Comment: Have you plotted the simple two ways? It looks like the patterns of interaction is different even though both are significant.

Comment: I examined the Sig in the output of the Test Results. My question is how to describe this in simple terms. Thanks

Comment: Your three-way interaction implies nothing about the simple two ways except that they are not the same. The best way to interpret the 3-way is to plot the two ways. Significance tests are not helpful (as I think you just discovered).

Comment: (1) So while conducting the 3-Way ANOVA, I request for all the possible 2-Way interactions (X*Y;  X*Z; Y*Z), and obviously the 3-Way (X*Y*Z) and the plots. And if there is any 2-Way interactions significant, I better follow up with a Post-Hoc. Is that the correct procedure? I also understand that the simple 2-Way interactions are different from observing the results in the Post-Hoc. Kindly advise.

Comment: There is no statistical basis to conduct tests of two-ways based on a significant 3-way although you might want to test a simple two way if you are interested in it for its own sake, not to understand the 3-way. Similarly, pairwise comparisons of means are not justified by a significant 2-way.

Comment: so do I understand the best method is to follow up with a post-hoc, if the 3-Way ANOVA is significant, rather than conducting simple two-ways. Thanks